# Possible error in Royden-Fitzpatrick

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm looking at Royden-Fitzpatrick, I don't know which printing, in Section 21.5 the proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem for $C(X)$.

In the paragraph starting "Define $\mu = \mu_{1} - \mu_{2}$...",  I don't follow the following argument: "We infer from this and Proposition 11 that the representation of $L$ as the difference of positive linear functionals is unique."  I don't follow.  In particular, is he assuming $\mu_{1} = \mu^{+}$ and $\mu_{2} = \mu^{-}$?  That's true, but it's not 100% obvious yet.

The way I would make the argument is $\|L\| \leq \|\mu\|_{TV}$ and thus $$\|\mu_{1}\|_{TV} + \|\mu_{2}\|_{TV} \leq \|\mu\|_{TV}$$ (since $\|L_{+}\| = \|\mu_{1}\|_{TV}$ and $\|L_{-}\| = \|\mu_{2}\|_{TV}$).  Therefore, $\|\mu\|_{TV} = \|\mu_{1}\|_{TV} + \|\mu_{2}\|_{TV}$.  It follows that $\mu_{1} \perp \mu_{2}$ so $\mu_{1} = \mu^{+}$ and $\mu_{2} = \mu^{-}$.

A consequence of what I just wrote is $\|L\| = \|\mu\|_{TV}$ so the map $T$ is injective.  Therefore, $L_{+}$ and $L_{-}$ are unique by the uniqueness of the Lebesgue decomposition of $\mu$.  (To be pedantic, $L_{+}$ and $L_{-}$ are the unique positive linear functionals for which $L = L_{+} - L_{-}$ **and** $\|L\| = \|L_{+}\| + \|L_{-}\|$.  The second part doesn't seem to be emphasized in the text.)

Comment: Yes, I also read this part of the proof and got confused. I think we can't get the "desirable" result "the representation of L as the difference of positive linear functional is unique." from Proposition 11. Instead, I think we can only get "L is bijective" from the position, because the kernel space of L contains only 0.

Comment: you may be interested in my [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990511) related to this issue.