# Uniqueness in the Riesz representation theorem for the dual of $C(X)$ in the book by Royden

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm reading the book **Real Analysis 4e by Royden** on the Riesz representation theorem for the dual of $C(X)$. I have two problems about the proof of this theorem. The book states the theorem this way in **page 464**,

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $C(X)$ the linear space of real-valued functions on $X$, normed by maximum norm. Define the operator $T: \textrm{Radon}(X)\to[C(X)]^*$ by setting, for $v\in \textrm{Radon}(X)$, $$T_v(f)=\int_X fdv$$ for all $f\in C(X)$. Then T is a linear isometric isomorphism of $\textrm{Radon}(X)$ onto $[C(X)]^*$.

Here $\textrm{Radon}(X)$ is the collection of all **signed Radon measures** on $X$ equiped with the norm, $$\|\mu\|=\mu^+(X)+\mu^-(X)$$ where $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ are unique Randon measures according Jordan decomposition.

In its proof, **1)** it begins by showing that any bounded linear functional $L$ in $[C(X)]^*$ can be represented as the difference of two positive linear functionals as $L=L_1-L_2$ with $\|L\|=L_1(1)+L_2(1)$, **without proving the uniqueness** of the $L_1$ and $L_2$. Then according the Riesz-Markov theorem which states that each positive linear functional $L_1$ can be **uniquely** expressed as $$L_1(f)=\int_X fd\mu_1$$ with a $\mu_1$ being a Radon measure, each bounded linear functional $L$ can be written as $$L(f)=L_1(f)-L_2(f)=\int_X fd\mu_1-\int_X fd\mu_2=\int_X fd(\mu_1-\mu_2)=\int_X fd\mu$$ with $\mu=\mu_1-\mu_2$ being a signed Randon measure. Thus $L=T_{\mu}$ and **the operator $T$ is onto.** Up to now, I can follow the argument. The following is what confuses me. It says **We infer from this and Proposition 11 that the representation of $L$ as the difference of positive linear functionals is unque**. The proposition 11 states that

> Let X be locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu_1,\mu_2$ be Radon measures on $X$ for which $$\int_X fd\mu_1=\int_X fd\mu_2$$ for all compact supported continuous function $f$ in $C_c(X)$. Then $\mu_1=\mu_2$.

**I don't understand how the uniqueness of the decomposition of $L$ can follow from this proposition and the fact that $T$ is onto:-(.**

**2)** The proof continues by showing that $$\|L\|=\mu_1(X)+\mu_2(X)=\|\mu\|$$ which I understand. It then immediately jumps to the conclusion that **Therefore T is an isometric isomorphism, which I have a little problem about.**

I tried to fill the missing details about the final jump myself. If I accept the argument before the final jump, then I think the proof, in summary, shows that any bounded linear functional $L$ can uniquely determine a signed Radon measure $\mu$ and thus the operator $T$ is one-to-one and onto. Also, obviously, $T$ is linear. **Therefore $T$ has a linear inverse $T^{-1}$.** The last formula  $\|L\|=\|\mu\|$ leads to the fact that $T$ and $T^{-1}$ both have a finite/bounded norm according the definition of the norm of operators ($\|T\|=sup_{\mu}\frac{\|T_{\mu}\|}{\|\mu\|}$ in this theorem). Thus, both  $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are bounded linear operators, i.e., continuous linear operators. Thus  $T$ is an isomorphism. $\|T\|$ happens to be $1$. This means it is also isometric isomorhphism which preserves the norms of $L$ and $\mu$. **Is my understanding about the final jump right ?**

Comment: What exactly do you call "the final jump"? I don't have the book at hand, but if you didn't misunderstand and misrepresent the argument, it's not quite correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer By "final jump", I mean the final conclusion that T is a isometric isomorhpism in the second to last paragraph. In the book, it concludes that T is a isometric isomorphism immediately after showing $\|T\|=\|\mu\|$.

Comment: Well, $\lVert T\mu\rVert = \lVert\mu\rVert$ for all $\mu$ is precisely the definition of $T$ being isometric (for linear $T$). This already proves that $T$ is injective, and that $T$ is surjective was shown before. There are some issues in the proof, at least in your representation of it, however. It is not true that the representation of $L$ as the difference of two positive functionals is unique (at least for nonempty $X$). Take any positive functional $P\neq 0$, then $L = L_1 - L_2 = (L_1 + P) - (L_2 + P)$ are two different representations of $L$ as a difference of positive functionals.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your tips and I may find what is the issue. In its proof of showing the decomposition of bounded linear functional, it also gives a property that $\|L\|=L_1(1)+L_2(1)$. So in this case, your example will increase the norm. This may be the issue. But I still don't know why the proposition 11 can guarantee the uniqueness. I'll check this in detail.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think the norm issue won't affect the final result, because the $\|T\|$ remains $1$. Maybe the decomposition of the functional is indeed not unique:-(. I am not sure if it is I or Royden who made a big mistake:-).

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, no. $\|L\|$ should remain, otherwise $\mu$ have to change accordingly. Then $T$ is no longer one-to-one. I have to think more about it:-(

Comment: The point is that there is a "minimal" decomposition of $L$ into a difference of positive functionals. Let's call a decomposition $L = L^+ - L^-$ of $L$ into a difference of positive functionals minimal if for every decomposition $L = L_1 - L_2$ into positive functionals the two functionals $L_1 - L^+$ and $L_2 - L^-$ are positive. Then it's clear that if a minimal decomposition exists, this is uniquely determined (since $T$ and $-T$ both positive implies $T=0$). Once you have any decomposition $L=L_1 - L_2$, you get a minimal decomposition from the Hahn decomposition of $\mu = \mu_1 - \mu_2$.

Comment: Then everything works out if you use the minimal decomposition, $\lVert L\rVert = L^+(1) + L^-(1)$ and so on.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I can understand your argument and it should work very well. But in the text, it gives an explicit construction of the two positive functionals, and though no minimality property is claimed in the construction, I feel the explicit construction procedure leaves no room for multiple choices. I am trying to figure out which step exactly guarantee the uniqueness.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have a problem about understanding the existence of the so-called minimal decomposition. Assume $L=f_++f_-$ and $L=g_++g_-$ are two decompositions of $L$. And WLOG, $f_+(h)-g_+(h)>0$ for ONE $h$ in $C(X)$. But we can't ensure that $f_+(h)-g_+(h)>0$ for ALL positive $h$ in $C(X)$. This means they does not necessarily differ by a positive functional. Then how do we expect a minimal decomposition ?

Comment: Correction: Should be $L=f_+-f_-$ and $L=g_+-g_-$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess I can make my point more clearer. Given two decompositions $L=f_+-f_-$ and $L=g_+-g_-$, then they only need to satisfy $f_+-g_+=f_- - g_-$ for each $h$ in $C(X)$. That is, the difference  $f_+-g_+$ only needs to be a linear functional, not necessarily to be POSITIVE linear functional at all. If so, there may be no minimal decoposition in THIS sense. Do I miss anything ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've lost track a little of what is in question here. I think that if we show the minimality of the constructed decomposition of $L$ as the difference of two positive linear functionals, the rest of the proof will be clear. If not, please request further elaboration.

Since I don't have access to Royden's book at the moment, I don't know how he constructs the decomposition. I expect it will be the standard method, though, which I first will sketch:

Let $P = \{ f \in C(X) : f \geqslant 0\}$. Then we start by constructing a functional $\Lambda_0 \colon P \to [0,+\infty)$ that dominates $L$. We define

$$\Lambda_0(f) = \sup \{ L(g) : g \in C(X), \, \lvert g\rvert \leqslant f\}.$$

Since $\lvert \pm f\rvert \leqslant f$ for $f\in P$, we have $\Lambda_0(f) \geqslant \max \{ L(f), L(-f)\} = \lvert L(f)\rvert \geqslant 0$, and since $\lvert L(g)\rvert \leqslant \lVert L\rVert\cdot\lVert g\rVert_\infty \leqslant \lVert L\rVert\cdot \lVert f\rVert_\infty$ for $\lvert g\rvert \leqslant f$, we have

$$0 \leqslant \Lambda_0(f) \leqslant \lVert L\rVert\cdot \lVert f\rVert_\infty$$

for $f\in P$.

Next one shows that $\Lambda_0(t\cdot f) = t\cdot \Lambda_0(f)$ for $t \in [0,+\infty)$ and $\Lambda_0(f + g) = \Lambda_0(f) + \Lambda_0(g)$ for $f,g \in P$. Thus one can extend $\Lambda_0$ to a positive linear functional $\Lambda_1$ on $C(X)$ by defining

$$\Lambda_1(f) = \Lambda_0(f^+) - \Lambda_0(f^-)$$

for $f \in C(X)$. One verifies that $\lVert\Lambda_1\rVert = \Lambda_1(1) = \lVert L\rVert$, and that $L_1 := \frac{1}{2}(\Lambda_1 + L)$ and $L_2 := \frac{1}{2}(\Lambda_1 - L)$ are positive linear functionals. Then one has the decomposition $L = L_1 - L_2$, and $\lVert L_1\rVert + \lVert L_2\rVert = L_1(1) + L_2(1) = \Lambda_1(1) = \lVert L\rVert$.

It remains to show the minimality of this decomposition. Suppose one has positive linear functionals $M_1, M_2$ with $L = M_1 - M_2$. We want to show that $M_1 - L_1 = M_2 - L_2$ are positive. So let $f \in P$, and $g \in C(X)$ with $\lvert g\rvert \leqslant f$. Then

\begin{align}
L(g) &= M_1(g) - M_2(g) \\
&= M_1(g^+ - g^-) - M_2(g^+ - g^-) \\
&= M_1(g^+) - M_1(g^-) - M_2(g^+) + M_2(g^-) \\
&\leqslant M_1(g^+) + M_1(g^-) + M_2(g^+) + M_2(g^-) \\
&= M_1(\lvert g\rvert) + M_2(\lvert g\rvert) \\
&\leqslant M_1(f) + M_2(f),
\end{align}

and thus $\Lambda_1(f) = \Lambda_0(f) \leqslant M_1(f) + M_2(f)$, from which we obtain

$$2L_1(f) = \Lambda_1(f) + L(f) \leqslant M_1(f) + M_2(f) + L(f) = M_1(f) + M_2(f) + M_1(f) - M_2(f) = 2M_1(f),$$

which is equivalent to the desired $M_1 - L_1 \geqslant 0$.

And by the minimality, we have

\begin{align}
\lVert M_1\rVert + \lVert M_2\rVert &= M_1(1) + M_2(1)\\
&= L_1(1) + L_2(1) + \bigl((M_1-L_1)(1) + (M_2 - L_2)(1)\bigr)\\
&\geqslant L_1(1) + L_2(1) = \lVert L\rVert,
\end{align}

with equality if and only if $0 = (M_1-L_1)(1) + (M_2-L_2)(1) = \lVert M_1 - L_1\rVert + \lVert M_2 - L_2\rVert$, i.e. $M_1 = L_1$ and therefore also $M_2 = L_2$.

While we do not have uniqueness of the decomposition of $L$ as the difference of two positive functionals (except in the trivial case $C(X) = \{0\}$, which happens for $X = \varnothing$) without side conditions, we have a unique decomposition with the additional condition that $\lVert L_1\rVert + \lVert L_2\rVert = \lVert L\rVert$.

The *existence* of this decomposition together with the Riesz-Markov theorem gives the existence of a Radon measure $\mu = \mu_1 - \mu_2$ with $T_\mu = T_{\mu_1} - T_{\mu_2} = L_1 - L_2 = L$ such that $\lVert\mu\rVert \leqslant \lVert\mu_1\rVert + \lVert\mu_2\rVert = \lVert L_1\rVert + \lVert L_2\rVert = \lVert L\rVert$. Since on the other hand one clearly has $\lVert T_\nu\rVert \leqslant \lVert\nu\rVert$ for every Radon measure $\nu$, it follows that $\lVert\mu\rVert = \lVert L\rVert$.